# Executing controlled number of threads between a given time in java

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I am having a list of requests in database. My application has to take the requests from DB and execute it in a thread. Only four threads can run at a time. Application should not process any requests before 9 AM and after 7 PM.

Could you please suggest the best way to implement this in java?
 Is Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor a good option?

Comment: How jdk's `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` to control thread?

Answer (score 1):

```
Only four threads can run at a time
```

For this you can use a Fixed Thread Pool Executor

```
Application should not process any requests before 9 AM and after 7 PM.
```

for this you must use a Cron Trigger in Spring Task Executor. Follow this [post](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

You should have totally 5 threads. One will be invoked by the Spring Task Executor when the Cron is Triggered and That thread should have a Fixed Thread Pool Executor which must spawn Child Threads. In this case maximum of 4.

Comment: Thanks!!. It will be great if you can explain what do you mean by Fixed Thread Pool Executer. Is there any such classes or is it the way we configure any of the classes? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at Executors class in Java 1.5 onwards http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html